# Как объединить ветки git

Tags: git

объясните пожалуйста мне как объединить ветки git. Делали проект с коллегой он тоже стажер, он создал ветку в git мне нужно скачать эту ветку в свою локальную ветку где лежит вторая половина работы и потом закинуть ее обратно в ту же ветку на bitbucket.

Comment: `git merge <branchname>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Сложный у Вас вопрос... Он вызывает в памяти картинку про GIT:

[image: картинка про GIT]

Но на самом деле не всё так печально. По сути, Вам нужно чтобы коллега сделал pull request в Вашу ветку, а вы его приняли и смержили со своей веткой.

После этого у Вас в ветке будет "объединение ваших работ".

А вот как это обратнов bitbucket залить - ну, если там git, то скорее всего, тоже сделать pull request.

Детали зависят от того, какими инструментами Вы пользуетесь. В `github`, `gitlab` и `gitea` есть довольно простой интерфейс, в котором можно все эти операции "накликать мышкой".

При использовании "чистой команднйо строки" придётся найти эти команды и попробовать всё сделать с их помощью.

Мой совет - прежде, чем сделать всё на "боевом проекте" - потренируйтесь "на кошечках"

Comment: а можно просто скачать его ветку в мою локальную? вроде  как fetch но для одной ветки?

Comment: Да, можно скачть ветку локально командой git clone <репозиторий> -b <имя ветки> . Например, скачать в отдельную папку и перенести все изменения куда надо "руками". Это "плохой совет", но если выбирать "мне работу делать или git изучать" - вполне приемлемо. В общем то, картинка как раз об этом

Comment: Руками не вариант там много мелких правок 2 дня пилили каждый свою половину. а сделать нужно  сегодня. (((

Comment: Ну, всё что Вам нужно - попробовать сделать так, как я написал в самом начале: сделать pull request и merge на его основе. При этом, если возникнут конфликты (т.е. автоматический мерж невозможен) - то всё равно придётся конфликты разруливать руками

Comment: @S.H.  В таких случаях лучше делать `git pull --rebase ...` обоим. Потом, кто второй, то есть не успел слиться с основной веткой, должен будет запускать ещё раз, и так пока оно не попадёт каким-то чудом (мейнтенер должен быть у проекта) в основную ветку.